# Get footprint of clipped 4-band VRT with nodata as polygon in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gdalbuildvrt, virtual-raster

For a 1 band image, I use

```
processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", {...,'NODATA':0})
processing.run('gdal:translate',{...,'EXTRA': '-b mask'})
processing.run('gdal:translate',{..., 'EXTRA': '-b 1', 'NODATA': 0})
processing.run('gdal:polygonize',{...,'OUTPUT': .../polygon_footprint.gpkg",'BAND': 1})
```

what do I need to change for a 4 band vrt-file as input? When I execute the clip with NoData set to zero, it seems to calculate eternally. When I set it to zero after the clip with another translate function, it calculates eternally on the rest of the functions...
When I run the clip function with NoData set to None, it works, but I do not know what the NoData value is. There is no NoData-Element in the xml-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a brand new GDAL utility "gdal_footprint" https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_footprint.html that is merged into the GDAL main branch just today https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/6264#event-9834853942.

> The gdal_footprint utility can be used to compute the footprint of a
> raster file, taking into account nodata values (or more generally the
> mask band attached to the raster bands), and generating
> polygons/multipolygons corresponding to areas where pixels are valid,
> and write to an output vector file.
>
> The nearblack utility may be run as a pre-processing step to generate
> proper mask bands.

If you can install GDAL-dev version I would recommend to test this program. It will be included in GDAL 3.8 version but it will take a few months before it is released.

Answer (score 0):

I did not actually have NoData = 0 in my code in the clip function. It works now.